# Kivy App using socket crashes on Android when I'm trying to send data

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, python-sockets

I've built an APK with buildozer from main.py and server.py is running on a raspberry pi. The code works fine and when I press the ON/OFF-button in the app on my phone, the script on the raspberry prints out the IP.

When I uncomment:

```
s.send(bytes('test', 'utf-8'))
```

... in main.py and:

```
msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
```

... in server.py, the app crashes as soon as I press the ON/OFF-button. When I run main.py on my computer, it works just fine.

What's the issue here? I can obviosly connect. The server does accept the incoming connection, but when I try to send something, it crashes.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import socket

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        StartPage = GridLayout()
        StartPage.cols = 1

        text = Label(text='SwitchPi')
        StartPage.add_widget(text)

        button = Button(text='ON/OFF')
        button.bind(on_press=self.btn)
        StartPage.add_widget(button)

        self.sm = ScreenManager()

        screen = Screen(name='start')
        screen.add_widget(StartPage)
        self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        return self.sm

    def btn(self, instance):

        ip = 'my ip address'

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, 1234))
        #s.send(bytes('test', 'utf-8'))

Main().run()
```

## server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(address)
    #msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    #print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: did you try somthing like s.send(b"test") as well? Actually I am pretty sure that this is not a kivy problem. It would help if you could try to reduce the problem to a bare minimum example. Personally I use pydroid3 to run small python scripts on my tablet to try things out. This way you can test the socket part withouth kivy at all and one does not need to create APK for every iteration.

Comment: Thank you for recommending pydroid3. Really neat app that I can use for other stuff. I wrote a simple client and tested it in pydroid3 and it works perfectly there. The issue must be related either to Kivy or the APK build process with buildozer.

Comment: I tried s.send(b'test') and it worked. Thank you. Any idea why s.send(bytes('test', 'utf-8')) works on both pydroid3 and Windows/Linux but not with kivy on android? I'm still pretty new to python.

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Maybe not all functionality is supported by the packing process or they missed an important part during the it. Normally I use send/recv only for "struct.pack" data anyway.